# why my StringReader doesn't read my txt file in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

This is my code and I want to read my TestFile.txt file and display it in txt2.Text, but this code doesn't read my txt file. anyone could help me to fixed this problem ? Thanks

```
Dim MyFileName As String = "C:\Users\TestFile.txt"
Dim Line As String = ""
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
Using sr As New StringReader(MyFileName)
Line = sr.ReadLine
  Do                     
      If Line = "*" Then
      Line = sr.ReadLine
         Do                            
           sb.Append(LineRead)           
           Line = sr.ReadLine
         Loop Until Line = "**"      
     End If
      Line = sr.ReadLine           
 Loop Until Line = ""              
End Using
Line = txt2.Text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not append `Line` to the `StringBuilder`, but `LineRead`, which is not set in your code.

Your code should read:

```
Line = sr.ReadLine
Do                            
    sb.Append(Line)           
    Line = sr.ReadLine
Loop Until Line = "**"
```

---

In the comments I've been advised to remove the following bit from my answer:

> The real problem are programming languages that don't force you to declare variables before you can use them. You gotta love VB.NET...

I'd like to quote the [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329/en-us#5) here:

> By default, the Visual Basic .NET or Visual Basic compiler enforces explicit variable declaration, which requires that you declare every variable before you use it. To change this default behavior, see the Change the Default Project Values section.

So, while by default the commenter is right, you *can* change the behavior, and nothing in the question tells me the OP didn't change it. Still, I'll rephrase my statement to be more precise:

> The real problem are programming languages that allow you to turn of the need to declare variables before you can use them. You gotta love VB.NET...

Comment: "The real problem are programming languages that don't force you to declare variables" -> VB.NET (even with Option String Off) forces you to declare variables. If "LineRead" is not declared somewhere, the OP's code wouldn't compile. Please correct this bit. What VB.NET allows (which C# doesn't) is not instantiating variables (because of assuming the default value); for example, it would be enough with writing: `Dim lineRead As String` (and VB.NET would assume that `lineRead` is `Nothing`).

Comment: (I guess that I am the commenter) I haven't ever seen anyone using `Option Explicit Off` but you are right: the option exists. The reason for my comment was highlighting that your original statement was more a generic critic with no (true/practical) motivation than an accurate guess. Writing "is `Option Explicit Off` written on the top" as a side comment/PS (just to make completely sure) sounds much more adequate than assuming from the start that `LineRead` wasn't declared and that this is the normal VB behaviour. "The real problem is using `Option Explicit Off`..." sounds also more accurate.

Comment: You are right about that. I just didn't want to give up my Visual Basic Rant :-)

Comment: I thought so :) (seriously, why are you hating VB so much? It is just a funny chap which just want make anyone else happy)

Comment: I don't really *hate* VB. I just don't consider it a *proper* programming language. But I guess that's just a matter of personal taste ;-)

Comment: "Don't consider it a proper programming language" sounds worse than hate: dispise. I think that these ideas are completely unmotivated, mainly within the .NET framework (where all the languages do exactly the same). But well... I know that it is just a superficial dispise. I guess that the differences in taste come from the different approaches to what a programming language is: a goal itself or a tool to accomplish a goal. For those thinking that it is a tool, the more userfriendly and practical the tool is, the better. In any case, I don't have any strong preference (am C#/VB bilingual).

Comment: You did realize I'm writing all this with a wink? ;-)

Comment: Come on... I know that you are kidding (I mean... this is the immediate conclusion I can extract from your high ranking). I am writing all this for any reader who might not have these ideas too clear. You would be surprised about how easily some statements are misunderstood by some (not-too-knowledgable) people... and this is what I am: an over-explainer :)

Answer (score 1):

[StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.stringreader.aspx) just lets you read from a string, it doesn't read or open a file.

Use a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) to read from a file.

```
  Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\TestFile.txt" 
  Dim Line As String = ""
  Dim sb As New StringBuilder
  Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText(filename)
    Line = sr.ReadLine
    Do                     
      If Line = "*" Then
         Line = sr.ReadLine
         Do                            
           sb.Append(Line) ' you probably meant Line, not LineRead      
           Line = sr.ReadLine
         Loop Until Line = "**"      
     End If
      Line = sr.ReadLine           
   Loop Until Line = ""
  End Using
```